# Password protecting an existing SQL Server Compact 4 database file

Tags: sql-server-ce-4

Can someone tell me how to password protect an existing SQL Server CE 4 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SqlCeEngine.Compact method, specify a password. Or you can use SqlCeCmd from a command line:

```
sqlcecmd40 
-d "Data Source=C:\test.sdf;" 
-z "Data Source=;Password=secret"
```

Comment: Thank you, but running the command against the file returns:

Error Code: 80004005
 Message   : The file that is being referenced is not a SQL Server Compact database file format. [ Databasename = c:\test.sdf ]
 Minor Err.: 25011
 Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
 Err. Par. : test.sdf

Comment: Use the 4.0 version (SqlCeCmd40.exe)

Comment: thank you! that solved my problem
I downloaded the software from: [here](http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/releases/view/25827)